What is the purpose of the long line with parallel notches, that spans the whole length of some electrical diagrams?

What is the purpose of the long line with parallel notches, that spans the whole length of some electrical diagrams?

What context is that diagram from? PLC's, power engineering? Different sub-fields might have their own conventions for specific things like this. Unless of course it's simply a drawing aid ruler.

You need to provide a citation for the image you have used.

As has already been commented, without context / citation we can't tell you. But if I had to guess I'd suggest that it indicated that the two parts of the circuit are physically separated somehow. Possibly the contacts on the right are in a control box or enclosure whilst those to the left are part of something bigger, but without more information this is pure speculation.

Peter J might have the right guess, as there appears to be a row of contacts or terminals C2/3/11 parallel with said line

Another think about that wiring diagram (I hesitate to call it a schematic) is the dot at the junction where two wires cross, the upper left hand corner.  This is considered not best practice as it can be hard to distinguish between two signals crossing each other with not connection and a connection where the dot may be fudged.  Generally all connections should be done with a Tee, as along the right side of the schematic.

This looks like something from a controls/industrial schematic.

Thanks for input, it is just an indication for physical separation. Its a control and power diagram for a reversible fan. The buttons are outside the line as they are outside the switchboard.
